# Why is PHP intl v.1.1.0 returning "El Salvador" for "-SV"?

Tags: php, locale, intl

I was going through the documentation, checking iso 2 digit country codes but I can't wrap my head around this. Everyone in the documentation it says that the 2 digit country code for Sweden is SV, yet it gives "El Salvador" back, when using this function

```
\Locale::getDisplayRegion('-SV', 'en')
```

According to [this](https://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php) site (and other sites as well), El Salvador should be "es-SV" and Sweden should be "SV" or "sv-SE". Let's say SV doesn't exist at all in the \Locale "db", but then why would it return El Salvador (which is "es-SV") and not Sweden (which is "sv-SE").

To be fair, it does return Sweden for "es-SV", but I think it's confusing.

Does anybody have a clue why is this happening?

Comment: 'sv' is the language code, while 'SE' is the country code. `sv-SE` = Svenska-Sverige, `es-SV` = Spanska-Salavador.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing the [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code](https://www.iban.com/country-codes) of Sweden (**[SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:SE)**) with the [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) language code of Swedish (`SV`).

The country code **[SV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes)** is **indeed** El-Salvador.

In the country locale `sv-SE`, the `sv` part means the language code (Swedish), and the `SE` part means the country code (Sweden), mostly distinguishing it from `sv-FI`, which is the variant of Swedish spoken/written in Finland (**[FI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:FI)**).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that! Much better answer than the one that has already been deleted under my post.